# fix windows 8 efi MBR - no success

Tags: linux

I have deleted the windows efi partition ( not windows ).I have in my system 2 linux distro and 2 efi partitions.

I am trying to fix windows boot following steps like:

[here](http://www.itechs-systems.com/fix_corrupt_UEFI_partition.aspx) and [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/).

The problem is , that when I enter the command:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

it shows :

> The system cannot find the file specified

I tried to run :

> bootrec /rebuildbcd

,so it shows:

> Successfully scanned Windows 
>   C:\Windows
>   Add installation to boot list?

I answer "Yes" and then it again throws me the previous message.

What can I do about that?

(The "This question may already have an answer here" doesn't help since the /fixboot doesn't work..)

---- UPDATE ----

1) I tried to run : `bcdboot c:\Windows` and it throws:

> BSFSVC Error:Failed to create a new system store

2) I typed `active`  after `assign letter  = v:` but it shows :

> The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk

3) I saw that in the directory : `C:\Windows\Boot\EFI\` it has the files : `bootmgr.efi` , `bootmgfw.efi`

Should I try there all the commands:

`bootrec /fixboot , fixmbr` or I may do things worse?

------ UPDATE ---------------------

This post is different from the duplicate one , in that  , when I try to run :

`bootrec /fixboot` , it shows: `The system cannot find the file specified`

I think I made this clear.Why do you duplicate this post???

--- UPDATE 2 -------------------------

I tried ( i have only 1 disk in my laptop ):

```
list disk
sel disk 0
list partition
sel partition 2 ( it is an efi partition I have created when I installed linux )
active -> gives message "The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk"
```

I then followed the same procedure:

```
list vol
sel vol 11
assign letter = v:
exit
```

Now , when I try: bootrec /fixboot , it shows me the message "No element found"

------UPDATE 3-------------------

I upload screenshots [here](http://prntscr.com/6crzus) and [here](http://prntscr.com/6cs1li).
Disk 0 is my laptop disk.
Disk 1 I don't know
Disk 2 is the flash drive from which I am running repair disk.

As for the partitions , the 2 and 10 are EFI partitions I generated from the linux distros.
So, the volumes are 11 and 12.
I tried both.

---------- UPDATE 4 ----------------------------------------------------

I tried :

```
 bootsect /nt60 ALL /force
```

but still nothing.
When I enter : `bootrec /fixboot` ,it shows :

> element not found.

Also, after this:

```
Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1]  D:\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes<Y>/No<N>/All<A>:
```

I enter Y but I am getting a negative answer ( I don't remember what exactly! ).

The good thing though ,is that now (after updating grub) the windows boot option appeared in my grub menu.
But when I select it ,it shows:

> The boot configuration data file is missing required information.
>
> File :\BCD 
>   Error Code: 0x0000034

I am not sure what to do from now on.

I saw somewhere to try : `bcdboot c:\windows` 
but I don't know how to access 'C' drive.
Ok, I am doing:

```
sel disk 0
list vol
```

and in volumes I can see 'C' listed .
But I don't know beyond this.

Also,I tried renaming the BCD file and then rebuild but still the same.

-----UPDATE 5--------------------------

Volume 10 contains:

```
Bin
Boot
Recovery -> empty
RicaTools -> bootmgr,bootmgr.efi ....
TFR
WinRePartition.ini
```

Volume 11:

```
EFI-> manjaro -> grubx64.efi
      BOOT-> BOOTx64.efi
      Microsoft-> Boot -> bootmgfw.efi
                          bootmgr.efi
                          boot.stl
                          MokManager
                          BCD
                          ...

     ->ubuntu-> grubx64.efi,grub.cfg,shimx64.efi
```

Volume 12:

```
EFI-> mint ->grubx64.efi
      manjaro-> grubx64.efi
```

---UPDATE 6------------------

Finally it worked thanks to Christophe!

Just want to note for anyone who has the same problem , that the last command `fixboot` gave

> Element not found

but it didn't matter!

Of course ,finaly,I had to do an `update-grub` .

Comment: @Moab:I checked this thread also, it uses the same steps.But my problem is after entering the bootrec /fixboot command , something that is not covered there.

Comment: You need to post more info on your exact problem, statements like "I don't remember" are not helpful. The more accurate and detailed info you post the better answers you will get here.

Comment: @Moab:I will check again the later message about MBR and I will update.The problem though is that I can't execute the command because it can't find the file path..

Comment: Why would you run `fixmbr` that command is only for MBR partitions.  If you have a EFI partition it means your using GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound:I don't know details.Everywhere I can see that.But fixboot doesn't work either

Comment: @George - We need details if you want help.  Your errors are identical to the duplicate thread.

Comment: @Ramhound:Can you tell me what else information do you want?I provided everything I know.In the other thread ,the /fixboot is working , my problem is that I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: @George - You followed the directions in the answer exactly and the command was unable to find your EFI boot drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I stopped at the bootrec /fixboot command as i say.

Comment: I still feel your running the wrong commands.  Its not your fault.  The answers to the duplicate question are absolutely horrible since most don't even apply to your situation since your using a GPT partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound:Ok,my knowledge is limited..:) .Have you any ideas?

Comment: Similar subject here: https://superuser.com/questions/707286/fix-gpt-on-win7   Follow the suggestions in the answer.

Comment: Ensure that the partition you wish to boot is marked as active.

Comment: @harrymc:I updated.It says The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the outputs of `list disk` and `list partition`.

Comment: @harrymc:It is a little difficult because I have to write it by hand.I will do it tomorrow though..But ,as I said I have 1 disk.As for the partitions I have a lot of them ( because I have 2 linux distros) but I know each one of them.So,I know that the one I chose is the EFI partition.

Comment: Can't you post screenshots, even using your phone camera?

Comment: @harrymc:I updated..

Comment: Disk 0 is an extremely partitioned GPT. I suggest a swiss knife to cut thru the tangle: Take a backup disk image of the entire disk, then take disk images of the Windows partitions, using a tool that can restore to a different-size partition. Then delete partitions 2 & 10, consolidate disk empty space, finally use Windows installation to recreate them with as close as possible their old sizes. Once created, take another disk image of the new partition (in case) then restore the old images. If this doesn't work, you will need to stay with the new Windows installation.

Comment: @harrymc:Thanks for your suggestions.A lot of things though..I 'll see what I 'll do , thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have any important data on your computer I advise you to boot on some Windows PE based CD/USB media with a GUI (Hiren's boot CD for example) and connect an external HDD to try backuping your important data.

Try to map the V: letter to the 260MB EFI partition by running the following diskpart commands:

```
diskpart
select volume 11
assign letter=v:
exit
```

Then rename the current Windows boot environment folder with the follwing command:

```
ren V:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot Boot.old
```

Re-create the Windows boot environment with [bcdboot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx):

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s V: /f UEFI
```

Afterwards, run [bootsect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(v=ws.10).aspx) which will look through your partitions, find the one with Windows 8 and update its boot code:

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL /force
```

Then re-run [bootrec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en) which this time should not output any errors :

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Finally, restart your computer to check if you are able to boot in Windows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21808/discussion-on-answer-by-christophe-fix-windows-8-efi-mbr-no-success).

Comment: @Christophe:Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!Excellent!!!!Thanks a lot man!!FInally!Accepted and upvoted!Please ,just edit the bcdboot command.I had to run bcdboot c:\windows /s v: /f uefi. Also,the last command , fixboot gave "element not found" , but it worked anyway!Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, I was glad to help. Oh yes I forgot C:\Windows, I made the edit. If you need to test/work on linux distros you can use virtualization software (VMware Workstation for example) instead of using multiboot. If will allow you to test a lot of stuff without breaking you boot environment.

Comment: @Christophe:I use only linux the last years.But , since I bought the laptop and it had installed windows , I just wanted to keep it.Now , I don't remember why I deleted in the first place but I thought I wouldn't have a problem loading windows from grub..Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much, my computer suddenly stopped booting and none of the startup repair stuff was working, also I couldn’t seem to run any of the commands the top google results were suggesting I run. However your answer worked perfectly and probably saves my PC. THank you from the bottom of my heart! (Except the /fixmbr part at the end, I just rebooted before that step and everything worked)